# Fastest way to find the index of the maximum of each row

Tags: r, matrix, range, max, min

I am trying to find an optimal way for finding the index of the maximum value in each row. The problem is that I cannot find a really efficient way in doing it.
An example:

```
Dummy <- matrix(runif(500000000,0,3), ncol = 10000)
> system.time(max.col(Dummy, "first"))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.532   0.075   5.599 
> system.time(apply(Dummy,1,which.max))
   user  system elapsed 
 14.638   0.210  14.828 
> system.time(rowRanges(Dummy))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.083   0.029   2.109
```

My main question is, why is it more than 2 times so slow to calculate the indices of the max value in comparison with calculating the max and the min with the rowRanges function. Is there a way how I can improve the performance of calculating the index of the max of each row?

Comment: The rowRanges is from the package matrixStats. Do you have the rcpp code for finding the index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pretty basic Rcpp implementation:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector MaxCol(Rcpp::NumericMatrix m) {
    R_xlen_t nr = m.nrow(), nc = m.ncol(), i = 0;
    Rcpp::NumericVector result(nr);

    for ( ; i < nr; i++) {
        double current = m(i, 0);
        R_xlen_t idx = 0, j = 1;
        for ( ; j < nc; j++) {
            if (m(i, j) > current) {
                current = m(i, j);
                idx = j;
            }
        }
        result[i] = idx + 1;
    }
    return result;
}

/*** R

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    "Rcpp" = MaxCol(Dummy), 
    "R" = max.col(Dummy, "first"),
    times = 200L
)
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# Rcpp 221.7777 224.7442 242.0089 229.6407 239.6339 455.9549   200
# R    513.4391 524.7585 562.7465 539.4829 562.3732 944.7587   200

*/
```

---

I had to scale your sample data down by an order of magnitude since my laptop did not have enough memory, but the results should translate on your original sample data:

```
Dummy <- matrix(runif(50000000,0,3), ncol = 10000)
all.equal(MaxCol(Dummy), max.col(Dummy, "first"))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

This can be changed slightly to return the indices of the `min` and `max` in each row:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix MinMaxCol(Rcpp::NumericMatrix m) {
    R_xlen_t nr = m.nrow(), nc = m.ncol(), i = 0;
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix result(nr, 2);

    for ( ; i < nr; i++) {
        double cmin = m(i, 0), cmax = m(i, 0);
        R_xlen_t min_idx = 0, max_idx = 0, j = 1;
        for ( ; j < nc; j++) {
            if (m(i, j) > cmax) {
                cmax = m(i, j);
                max_idx = j;
            }
            if (m(i, j) < cmin) {
                cmin = m(i, j);
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }
        result(i, 0) = min_idx + 1;
        result(i, 1) = max_idx + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction!! Great work. Is it also possible to both return the indices of the max and the min and also calculate he value of the max and the min in one Rccp code? That would help me a lot!

Comment: I've added a version that returns the indices for the `min` and `max` value. I'm not sure what kind of output you would want for including the values as well as the indices, possibly a four column matrix? You could change the above to initialize a `nrow x 4` column result matrix, and just assign the `cmax` and `cmin` values in the other two columns, if so.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on krlmlr's answer, some benchmarks:

On dataset:

```
set.seed(007); Dummy <- matrix(runif(50000000,0,3), ncol = 1000)
```

`maxCol_R` is an R by-column loop, `maxCol_col` is a C by-column loop, `maxCol_row` is a C by-row loop.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(max.col(Dummy, "first"), maxCol_R(Dummy), maxCol_col(Dummy), maxCol_row(Dummy), times = 30)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                    expr        min         lq     median         uq       max neval
# max.col(Dummy, "first") 1209.28408 1245.24872 1268.34146 1291.26612 1504.0072    30
#         maxCol_R(Dummy) 1060.99994 1084.80260 1099.41400 1154.11213 1436.2136    30
#       maxCol_col(Dummy)   86.52765   87.22713   89.00142   93.29838  122.2456    30
#       maxCol_row(Dummy)  577.51613  583.96600  598.76010  616.88250  671.9191    30
all.equal(max.col(Dummy, "first"), maxCol_R(Dummy))
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(max.col(Dummy, "first"), maxCol_col(Dummy))
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(max.col(Dummy, "first"), maxCol_row(Dummy))
#[1] TRUE
```

And the functions:

```
maxCol_R = function(x)
{
    ans = rep_len(1L, nrow(x))
    mx = x[, 1L]

    for(j in 2:ncol(x)) {
        tmp = x[, j]
        wh = which(tmp > mx)

        ans[wh] = j
        mx[wh] = tmp[wh]
    }

    ans
} 

maxCol_col = inline::cfunction(sig = c(x = "matrix"), body = '
    int nr = INTEGER(getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol))[0], nc = INTEGER(getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol))[1]; 
    double *px = REAL(x), *buf = (double *) R_alloc(nr, sizeof(double));
    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) buf[i] = R_NegInf;

    SEXP ans = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, nr));
    int *pans = INTEGER(ans);

    for(int j = 0; j < nc; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
            if(px[i + j*nr] > buf[i]) {
                buf[i] = px[i + j*nr];
                pans[i] = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(ans);
', language = "C")

maxCol_row = inline::cfunction(sig = c(x = "matrix"), body = '
    int nr = INTEGER(getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol))[0], nc = INTEGER(getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol))[1]; 
    double *px = REAL(x), *buf = (double *) R_alloc(nr, sizeof(double));
    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) buf[i] = R_NegInf;

    SEXP ans = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, nr));
    int *pans = INTEGER(ans);

    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < nc; j++) {
            if(px[i + j*nr] > buf[i]) {
                buf[i] = px[i + j*nr];
                pans[i] = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(ans);
', language = "C")
```

***EDIT*** Jun 10 '16

With slight changes to find the indices of both max and min:

```
rangeCol = inline::cfunction(sig = c(x = "matrix"), body = '
    int nr = INTEGER(getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol))[0], nc = INTEGER(getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol))[1]; 
    double *px = REAL(x), 
           *maxbuf = (double *) R_alloc(nr, sizeof(double)),
           *minbuf = (double *) R_alloc(nr, sizeof(double));
    memcpy(maxbuf, &(px[0 + 0*nr]), nr * sizeof(double));
    memcpy(minbuf, &(px[0 + 0*nr]), nr * sizeof(double));

    SEXP ans = PROTECT(allocMatrix(INTSXP, nr, 2));
    int *pans = INTEGER(ans); 
    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(ans); i++) pans[i] = 1;

    for(int j = 1; j < nc; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
            if(px[i + j*nr] > maxbuf[i]) {
                maxbuf[i] = px[i + j*nr];
                pans[i] = j + 1;
            }
            if(px[i + j*nr] < minbuf[i]) {
                minbuf[i] = px[i + j*nr];
                pans[i + nr] = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(ans);
', language = "C")

set.seed(007); m = matrix(sample(24) + 0, 6, 4)
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   24    7   23    6
#[2,]   10   17   21   11
#[3,]    3   22   20   14
#[4,]    2   18    1   15
#[5,]    5   19   12    8
#[6,]   16    4    9   13
rangeCol(m)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    3    1
#[3,]    2    1
#[4,]    2    3
#[5,]    2    1
#[6,]    1    2
```

Comment: That's an impressive difference!

Comment: I am trying to adjust the maxCol_Col function to also output the index of the minimum value of each row, but I am stuck because I don't have experiences with writing in C. Could you maybe provide the adjustments that have to made in the MaxCol_Col function to calculate the min and the max indices of each row?

Comment: @TobiasDekker : made an edit to return `[max, min]` indices for each row

Answer (score 3):

R stores matrices in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). Therefore, iterating over the *columns* will be usually faster because the values for one column are close to each other in memory and will travel through the cache hierarchy in one go:

```
Dummy <- matrix(runif(100000000,0,3), ncol = 10000)
system.time(apply(Dummy,1,function(x) NULL))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  1.360   0.160   1.519 
system.time(apply(Dummy,2,function(x) NULL))
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.94    0.12    1.06
```

This should be close to the minimal time even the fastest Rcpp solution will be able to obtain. Any solution that uses `apply()` will have to copy each column/row, this can be saved when using Rcpp. You decide if the potential speed-up by a factor of 2 is worth the effort to you.

Comment: In addition to the efficiency of by-column accessing, assuming that "Dummy", in OP, has much fewer columns, a simple by-column loop that updates the index of the current maximum might be efficient enough in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the fastest way to do things in R is to call C, C++, or FORTRAN.

It appears that `matrixStats::rowRanges` is [implemented in C](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats/blob/master/src/rowRanges.c) which explains why it is the fastest.

If you want to improve performance even more, there is presumably a little bit of speed to gain in modifying the `rowRanges.c` code to ignore the minimum and just get the maximum, but I think the gains will be very small.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with STL algorithms and RcppArmadillo.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(MaxColArmadillo(Dummy), #Using RcppArmadillo
                               MaxColAlgorithm(Dummy), #Using STL algorithm max_element
                               maxCol_col(Dummy), #Column processing
                               maxCol_row(Dummy)) #Row processing

Unit: milliseconds
                   expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
 MaxColArmadillo(Dummy) 227.95864 235.01426 261.4913 250.17897 276.7593 399.6183   100
 MaxColAlgorithm(Dummy) 292.77041 345.84008 392.1704 390.66578 433.8009 552.2349   100
      maxCol_col(Dummy)  40.64343  42.41487  53.7250  48.10126  61.3781 128.4968   100
      maxCol_row(Dummy) 146.96077 158.84512 173.0941 169.20323 178.7959 272.6261   100
```

STL implementation

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]

// Argument is a matrix ansd returns a 
// vector of max of each of the rows of the matrix

Rcpp::NumericVector MaxColAlgorithm(Rcpp::NumericMatrix m) {

//int numOfRows = m.rows();

//Create vector with 0 of size numOfRows
Rcpp::NumericVector total(m.rows());

  for(int i = 0; i < m.rows(); ++i)
  {
    //Create vector of the rows of matrix
    Rcpp::NumericVector rVec = m.row(i);

    //Apply STL max of elemsnts on the vector and store in a vector
    total(i) = *std::max_element(rVec.begin(), rVec.end());
  }

  return total;

}
```

RcppArmadillo implementation

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat MaxColArmadillo(arma::mat x) 
{
  //RcppArmadillo max function where dim = 1 means max of each row
  // of the matrix
  return(max(x,1)); 
}
```